# How to combine $(this) and $('.other') into single line

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How to combine $(this) and $('.other') into single line?

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.other').addClass('active');
});
```

Something like this but I know this is not correct:

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
    $(this, '.other').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: What's wrong with the first option?

Comment: @Scott: It's not DRY. Granted, it's just a single method call with a single argument, but still.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: Thanks Bergi. This what I need. But you replied in comment so how to accept ur answer?

Answer (score -1):

$('.menu').click(function(){
var ctrls = '#' + $(this).attr('Id') + ', .other';
    $(ctrls).addClass('active');
});

Comment: Explain it properly. What changes you have done in code and why?

Comment: If you need explanation you must request for that, OK.

Comment: Ans: n Jquery Selector object and tags cannot be concatenated so I took the Id of the this object and concatenated with the class. 
var ctrls = '#' + $(this).attr('Id') + ', .other';
'ctrls' is a string of selected items

I hope you have the knowledge to understand the rest

Comment: Thank you @RageshMK but this approach doesn't shorten the original problem. I prefer using .add() as pointed by Bergi